# On energy conservation and time-ordered interaction diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, energy-conservation, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

I've found the following lectures given by [professor Mark Thomson](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Ethomson/) (here's his *[particle physics](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Ethomson/partIIIparticles/)* web page); in the third one, *[Interaction by particle exchange and QED](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Ethomson/partIIIparticles/handouts/Handout_3_2011.pdf)*, it's stated that **time-ordered QM does not conserve energy**:
[image]

**Why is that?** Is it due to the time-asymmetry (irreversibility) of the process (Noether's theorem)?

*Addendum*. I've probably understood why time-ordering is not convenient. The chronological order of two events depends on the system of reference, so it's not Lorentz-invariant. **But**, if this is the case, then why is the relation $E^2-|\vec p|^2 = m^2$ valid on the left-hand side, and not on the right-hand side (Feynman diagram) where this invariance is claimed to be present?